# Manually invoke the jquery validation to show input errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I got a form in which I'm using unobtrusive jquery validation and I just wanted to save myself the trouble of creating custom client side validation attributes for checking input file size and captcha since I'm not reusing them anywhere else.

The problem is if I do the `onclick="return formValidation();"` all will be fine but the captcha and file size error appear before the jquery validation since the form is not posted and is actually prevented from being posted as the function returns false. But I want all errors to be shown at the same time. So I do

```
function formValidation(){
      $validator.showError() // put here on purpose to test if it is blocking
      return checkCaptcha() && checkFileSize() == true;
 }
```

I see that nothing can be executed after the '$validator.showError()". Since I'm not a JQuery and JavaScript enthusiast I gotta admit that I just find the `$validator.showError()` in an accepted answer in StackOverFlow so I'm unsure if it is actually correct. Looking for the solution.

Comment: @ArcaneCraeda: let me know what part of the post solve the problem.

Comment: @ArcaneCraeda: And if you read the title you see the asker wanted to manually trigger not showing errors before triggering!

Comment: @ArcaneCraeda: Already came across that, it doesn't work in my case

Comment: @ArcaneCraeda: FYI, error message are automatically set according to the user language by ASP.NET resource files. not by using .val()

Comment: no reason that `valid()` method shouldn't work. Need to explain why it doesn't

Comment: @charlietfl: the valid method DOES work, it doesn't show the error, it only gives me true and false values.

Comment: it also should show errors if you have configured validation properly

Comment: @charlietfl: No it doesn't, could this be because this is unobtrusive jquery validation?

Comment: @charlietfl: And I don't wanna harcode any error message, I want to use the ones that are pushed in the html by ASP.Net MVC. so I just wanna show errors making them visible, don't care if the form is valid or not.

Comment: create a demo that replicates problem. Can use cdn resources for the validation scripts

Comment: I can't do it in fiddler, it's ASP.Net MVC, many things have something to do with .Net and C#.

Comment: no they don't ...once it is in browser MVC has nothing to do with how browser works

Comment: @charlietfl: the page is rendered in the server side and the errors, validation, all other stuff are rendered on demand, no logic is bind with the html.

Comment: @charlietfl: and the JQuery Validate library is the Microsoft implementation of it.

Comment: which is readily available on cdn also

Comment: @charlietfl: not using cdn since I have the optimization enabled, and it has great advantages as anytime you make any changes to the JS, the filename and it's signature changes forcing the browser to use the new one. No caching issue then.

Comment: well if you want help, a demo that replicates problem is the answer

Comment: @charlietfl: anyways it can't be shown in fiddler since the point is no harcoding, if I wanna do it then why would I post the question, I'd set up the error over JQuery manually, I'm not that stupid.